# How to access the properties of a nested class with the instance of outer class

Tags: c#, .net

I have this example

```
 public class AClass
{
     public class BClass
     {
         public string name;
         public string id;
     }

}
```

now i want to make an intsance of `Aclass`

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        AClass newitem = new AClass();

    }
}
```

but i haven't access to the properties of `BClass` with the object `newitem`. How can achieve that with an instance of `AClass`?

Comment: If you haven't instantiated a class of type `AClass.BClass` then there is no `BClass` whose properties you can get.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The code you've provided so far doesn't create any instances of `BClass`, so no, you wouldn't be able to access any members. (Note that you've also provided fields, not properties.) What are you trying to achieve here? Why have you used a nested class at all? There are perfectly good reasons for using nested classes, but until we know what you're trying to achieve we won't be able to tell whether it's a good idea in your case or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class A and Class B don't have a relationship in this case. Sounds like you might want to make an object of type `BClass` a property of `AClass`.

```
 public class AClass
 {
     public BClass BClass { get; set; }
 }

 public class BClass
 {
     public string name;
     public string id;
 }
```

---

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        AClass newitem = new AClass();
        BClass myBClass = newitem.BClass;
    }
}
```